# Range.Areas returns incorrect number of rows

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I have a VBA application that downloads all HTML tables from a website and parses them to a worksheet. Then I wrote code that will find a string in the header of each table in Column A, activate that cell, identify the range of the currentregion, and add a listobject name to the worksheet name manager. The problem I am having is with code line 260 where the message box displays the number of rows in the table. The number is always the same even when the tables have a different number of rows. I believe the problem is in code lines 210 through 250. I have searched all over the web including stack overflow and cannot find a solution.

Can anyone see why the number displayed in the message box does not reflect the number of rows in the table?

```
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Method : test_currentregion_IncludeHeaders
' Author : Richard
' Date   : 10/4/2016
' Purpose: Find cell with value and turn into named table with headers
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub test_currentregion_IncludeHeaders()

10        On Error GoTo test_currentregion_IncludeHeaders_Error

          'convert all tables (listobjects) to ranges
          Dim WS As Worksheet, LO As ListObject
20        For Each WS In Worksheets
30            For Each LO In WS.ListObjects
40                LO.Unlist
50            Next
60        Next

          'find currentregions and add table
          Dim tbl As Object
          Dim c As Object
          Dim firstAddress As Variant
          Dim Hdr As String
          Dim rngTable As Range
          Dim rows As Long
          Dim Line As Variant
          Dim iCounter As Long

70        Hdr = "Header"
80        iCounter = 1
90        rows = 0

100       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A")
110           Set c = .Find(Hdr, LookIn:=xlValues)
120           If Not c Is Nothing Then
130               firstAddress = c.Address
140               c.Select        'must select object
150           End If

160       Do

170       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
180           Set rngTable = c.CurrentRegion
190           .ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=xlSrcRange, Source:=rngTable, _
              xlListObjectHasHeaders:=xlYes, TableStyleName:="TableStyleMedium1") _
              .Name = "List" & iCounter
200       End With

210       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1)
220           For Each Line In .Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas
230               rows = rows + Line.rows.Count
240           Next
250       End With

260       MsgBox "Number of rows displayed = " & rows

          'reset selected variables
270           iCounter = iCounter + 1
280           rows = 0
290           Set Line = Nothing

          'find next currentregion
300           Set c = .FindNext(c)
310       Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
320    End With

330       On Error GoTo 0
340       Exit Sub

test_currentregion_IncludeHeaders_Error:

350       MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure_test_currentregion_IncludeHeaders of Sub current_region"

End Sub
```

Comment: I included a link to the macro enabled workbook on OneDrive.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39907765/edit) to include the smallest part of the code necessary to show the problem.  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more on asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: `test_currentregion_IncludeHeaders` isn't too big to use in your post.

Answer (score 2):

The issue that you are having is that you are always referring to the first ListObject `.ListObjects(1)`.

You can access the Listobject that a range belongs to and return its rows count (Excluding Headers) like this:

`rows = rngTable.ListObject.DataBodyRange.rows.Count`